# How to use Facebook Graph API to upload image to Apps own page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a PHP script to upload photos to an Apps own Fan Page and for them to appear large in the Fan Page timeline. Similar to https://www.facebook.com/Instagram.

This is the code I have but although it's using page_id in the OpenGraph URL it keeps posting to my personal photo albums, not the Page albums.

```
<?php

    $app_id = "APP_ID";
    $app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
    $post_login_url = "LOGIN_URL";
    $fan_page_id = "PAGE_ID";

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream,manage_pages permission 
    if(empty($code)){ 
        $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
        . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
        . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
        . "&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages";
        echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
    }
    else {
        $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
        . "client_id=" . $app_id 
        . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
        . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
        . "&code=" . $code;
        $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);
        $access_token = $params['access_token'];

    // Show photo upload form to user and post to the Graph URL
    $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/".$fan_page_id."/photos?access_token=" .$access_token;

    echo '<html><body>';
    echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="' .$graph_url .' "method="POST">';
    echo 'Please choose a photo: ';
    echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</body></html>';
    }
?>
```

Code sample v2 which doesn't return anything from CURL

```
    $fb_page_id = "fb_page_id";
    $user_id = 'user_id'; 
    $fb_access_token = 'fb_access_token';

    $args = array(
        'url' => 'http://www.mysite.com/savefiles/smalls/comps/1/comp_1_600.jpg',
        'message' => 'SOME CAPTION TEXT'
    );
//Get Page Access Token - (as opposed to your user access token - requires manage_pages permission)
    $accounts = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user_id.'/accounts?access_token='.$fb_access_token;
    $accounts_data = file_get_contents($accounts,0,null,null);
    $account_data = json_decode($accounts_data, true);

    foreach ($account_data['data'] as $accountdata) {

        $account_page_id = $accountdata['id'];
        $page_access_token = $accountdata['access_token'];
        if($account_page_id == $fb_page_id){
            $my_page_access_token = $page_access_token; 
            //echo $my_page_access_token . '<br/>';
        }   
    }

    //Not Tested - Just in Case     
    if($my_page_access_token==''){
        $my_page_access_token = $fb_access_token;
    }

//Make Upload Call
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_page_id.'/photos?access_token='.$my_page_access_token;
   // echo $url . '<br/>';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $post_object = json_decode($data);
    $post_data = get_object_vars($post_object);
    $post_id = $post_data['post_id'];
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to upload a photo to your app page just like you would any other page. First set your upload arguments to pass to Facebook:

```
$args = array(
    'url' => 'URL-OF-IMAGE' ,
    'message' => 'SOME CAPTION TEXT'
    );
```

In the next steps, make sure you already have your user id, your page's id, and a valid access token:

```
//Get Page Access Token - (as opposed to your user access token - requires manage_pages permission)
$accounts = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user_id.'/accounts?access_token='.$fb_access_token;

    $accounts_data = file_get_contents($accounts,0,null,null);

    $account_data = json_decode($accounts_data, true);

    foreach ($account_data['data'] as $accountdata) {

        $account_page_id = $accountdata['id'];

        $page_access_token = $accountdata['access_token'];

        if($account_page_id == $fb_page_id){

            $my_page_access_token = $page_access_token; 

            //echo $my_page_access_token . '<br/>';
        }   
    }

//Not Tested - Just in Case     
if($my_page_access_token==''){
    $my_page_access_token = $fb_access_token;
}

    //Make Upload Call
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_page_id.'/photos?access_token='.$my_page_access_token;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $post_object = json_decode($data);
    $post_data = get_object_vars($post_object);
    $post_id = $post_data['post_id'];
    curl_close($ch);
```

This will upload your photo to an album on your page that has the same name of your app. If this album doesn't already exist, it will be automatically created up first upload. This photo will also show up on your timeline with your caption. Most of the code above is tested and works as is as long as you have proper authentication, variable data such as page ids, user ids and access tokens, and your parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. I'm fairly sure I've set it up OK but I get nothing returned from curl exec ($data = curl_exec($ch)). I echoed $url and that looks to be fine. Permissions for the page are  "perms":["ADMINISTER","EDIT_PROFILE","CREATE_CONTENT","MODERATE_CONTENT","CREATE_ADS","BASIC_ADMIN"] Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you will need the MANAGE_PAGES permission in order to upload a photo to a page

Comment: EDIT: sorry above it looks like you have the manage_pages permission in your scope..I can't really help you further without seeing your code..other than telling to make sure your access token hasn't expired..I like to trade mine in for an extended token

Comment: Added the code I'm trying above "Code sample v2". It doesn't have the access code so not sure if you can help without them? Thanks.

Comment: uncomment the `echo $my_page_access_token;` line and see if you're getting a value there. If not, that's probably your problem. If you don't have a value there, do a `print_r($account_data);` above the foreach and see what you get. I know the code works because it's running on my app right now.

Comment: Yes, got it working! Had to add a couple of extra options as the CURL was giving error 400. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); Thanks for your help!

Comment: aaah, that will do it..guessing that was a server-specific issue? Anyway glad you got it working! Happy to help!